# How to create tokens in ethereum without using cyrptocurrency?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I am new to blockchain. I have read that tokens are created using smart contracts in Ethereum. Smart contracts need ether to be created. Is there anyway that I can create tokens without using ether or any other cryptocurrency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way to do this. This is an essential component of the Ethereum Blockchain as it prevents a DDOS like attack on the network. Think of it like this: if there was no cost involved in deploying a smart contract someone could just spam the network and create billions of smart contract. Very quickly the entire network would collapse.

However there are ways to get a little bit of free Ethereum. For example you could use a faucet which will distribute a little bit of Ethereum. Usually these faucets distribute Ethereum for testnet versions of the Ethereum network.

For example take a look at the [Rinkeby](https://www.rinkeby.io) testnet. They have their own [faucet](https://www.rinkeby.io/#faucet) which will allow you to get a little bit of Ethereum for testing purposes.

There may be faucets which work on mainnet. However keep in mind there is no such thing as a free lunch. Someone somewhere will eventually have to pay the bill.

Comment: Thank you. I had another query : What about other blockchain platforms like Hyperledger, do they require some sort of payment for smart contracts too? I want to avoid the use of cryptocurrency because it is still not globally acceptable.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Hyperledger but the the concept of having to pay gas (either via the primary currency or some other derived token) is pretty well established in the blockchain world.